# Wer besetzt eine Rolle?

Tags: word-usage

Für mein Gefühl wären

> [Castingmensch] besetzte die Rolle des [Charakters] mit [Schauspieler]

bzw.

> [Schauspieler] spielte die Rolle des [Charakters]

Jetzt will mir aber jemand

> [Schauspieler] besetzte die Rolle des [Charakters]

unterjubeln. Kann man das (vielleicht sogar film-fachsprachlich) so sagen? (Wohlgemerkt ist der Schauspieler nicht in Personalunion auch Caster des Films) Ich vermute, man will etwas weniger Spielerisches als eben "spielen" verwenden und auch nichts allzu subjektiv Wirkendes wie "füllte die Rolle aus".

Answer (score 2):

*besetzen* hat eben mindestens zwei Hauptbedeutungen:

1. Etwas (selbst) besetzen,

> Klaus besetzt schon den ganzen Morgen die Toilette

(und nein, Klaus sitzt nicht vor der Tür und weist die Keramiken zu...) Diese Bedeutung wäre die, bei der ein Schauspieler eine Rolle *ausfüllt*.
Zugegeben, die Verwendung ist eher ungewöhnlich (und, wegen (2) auch ziemlich mißverständlich und deswegen wohl auch eher nicht empfehlenswert). Klassisch würde man eher etwas sagen wie "Müller **gibt** den 'Jedermann' in Salzburg" oder "Patrick Stewart **spielt** Jean-Luc Picard".

2. Etwas mit etwas/jemand anderem besetzen

> Dass Tarantino die Rolle des Dr. King Schulz mit Christoph Waltz besetzte, war schon fast zwingend

Diese Bedeutung ist sehr spezialisiert auf Schauspiel und Kino, oder Stellen und Ämter - Natürlich kann man auch ein Land mit Truppen besetzen, die Aktion ist aber eine andere.

Comment: "geben" ist schon mal ein guter Tipp. Scheint mir persönlich aber (Gefühl, Gefühl) eher zu Theater als Film zu passen, oder? "Patrick Stewart gab 2006 den Prospero in 'Der Sturm'" finde ich okay, aber  "Patrick Stewart gab den Stallmeister in 'Der kleine Lord'" (von mir aus auch prominenter "Patrick Stewart gab viele Jahre den Captain Picard") empfinde ich als merkwürdig

Comment: Ich stimme dir zu, dass "geben" nicht gut für Kino und TV passt - Da wird man wohl lieber "spielen" nehmen müssen.

Answer (score 0):

Der Sachverhalt lässt sich klären, ohne die Bedeutung des Verbs von *»etwas bestücken«* (z.B. eine Rolle mit einem Schauspieler) zu *»einen Platz einnehmen«* (z.B. auf einer Toilette) zu ändern. Dass sich mit einer Änderung der Bedeutung die Interpretation der anderen Satzglieder verändern kann, liegt auf der Hand, sagt aber wenig darüber aus, wie die Satzglieder zu interpretieren sind, wenn das Verb in der ursprünglichen Bedeutung verwendet wird. (Toiletten sind bei der Erklärung von Rollenbesetzungen so hilfreich wie Laufschuhe bei der Erklärung von *»meine Nase läuft.«*)

---

Fangen wir mit diesem Satz an:

> Nachdem Irene eine Rolle mit Klaus besetzt hat, ist die Rolle mit Klaus besetzt.

Machen wir den Nebensatz zu einem Hauptsatz:

> Die Rolle ist mit Klaus besetzt.

Hier liegt ein klassischer Zustandspassiv vor. Das Präpositionalobjekt *»mit Klaus«* ist ein optionaler Zusatz, der weggelassen werden kann. Stattdessen kann man in einem Vorgangspassiv den Akteur (wer hat die Besetzung durchgeführt?) durch ein anderes Präpositionalobjekt angeben, wobei zwei verschiedene Präpositionen zur Wahl stehen:

> Die Rolle wurde durch Irene besetzt.
> Die Rolle wurde von Irene besetzt.

Bei der Variante mit *»durch«* ist eindeutig klar, dass Irene die Veranlasserin ist, und denselben Satz als Zustandspassiv empfinde ich persönlich als falsch, oder zumindest als unglücklich formuliert:

> Die Rolle ist durch Irene besetzt.

Wenn man aber die Variante mit *»von«* als Zustandspassiv formuliert und eine neue Person einführt, ist plötzlich unklar, ob diese Person die Besetzung durchgeführt hat, oder ob diese Person Inhaber der Rolle ist:

> Die Rolle ist von Kurt besetzt.

Beide Deutungen sind möglich, denn dieser Satz lebt in einer Zwischenwelt zwischen diesen beiden Sätzen, die beide eindeutig sind:

> Die Rolle wurde von Kurt besetzt.
> Die Rolle ist mit Kurt besetzt.

Während *»... ist durch ...«* zu keiner der beiden Möglichkeiten passen will, ist *»... ist von ...«* mit beiden Deutungen kompatibel. Ohne Kontext kann nicht entschieden werden, ob Kurt im Satz *»Die Rolle ist von Kurt besetzt«* der Regisseur oder ein Schauspieler ist.

Diese Ambiguität bleibt aber nur zum Teil bestehen, wenn man den Passiv-Satz in einen Aktiv-Satz umwandelt:

> Zustandspassiv: Die Rolle ist von Kurt besetzt.
> Aktiv: Kurt besetzt die Rolle.

Der Aktiv-Satz möchte lieber dahingehend interpretiert werden, dass Kurt der Regisseur ist, denn derselbe Aktivsatz passt auch gut zu einem anderen Passiv-Satz:

> Aktiv: Kurt besetzt die Rolle.
> Vorgangspassiv: Die Rolle wird von Kurt besetzt.

Im Präteritum drängt sich diese Deutung sogar noch mehr vor:

> Aktiv: Kurt besetzte die Rolle.
> Vorgangspassiv: Die Rolle wurde von Kurt besetzt.
> Zustandspassiv: Die Rolle war von Kurt besetzt.

Aber obwohl der Aktiv-Satz danach drängt, so interpretiert zu werden, dass Kurt der Regisseur ist, ist die Interpretation, dass er ein Schauspieler ist, nicht falsch. Vor allem dann, wenn der Kontext ganz klar diese Interpretation vorgibt, spricht nichts dagegen, den Satz so zu verwenden.

---

Zur Verwendung des Verbs *»besetzen«* im Sinn von *»bestücken«*:

Es werden nicht nur Rollen in Film und Theater mit Schauspielern besetzt. Der Begriff ist also keineswegs auf Schauspiel und Kino spezialisiert, wie in einer anderen Antwort behauptet wurde.

Ich unterrichte an einer Fachhochschule, und die Studiengangsleiter besetzen die einzelnen Unterrichtsfächer mit Lektoren und Dozenten. Da die Lehrperson einer gewissen Fluktuation unterliegen, und sich gerade an Hochschulen auch die Lehrfächer immer wieder ändern, muss daher jedes Semester eine neue Besetzungsliste erstellt werden.

Ich singe aber auch in einem Chor, und wir führen pro Saison ca. ein Duzend unterschiedliche Werke auf, wobei es Werke gibt, wo nur Frauen singen (3. Symphonie von G. Mahler) oder nur Männer (13. Symphonie von D. Schostakowitsch). Es gibt Werke, wo mindestens 150 Sänger auf der Bühne stehen sollten (8. Symphonie von G. Mahler) und welche, die kaum mehr als 50 Sänger vertragen (alle Kantaten von J.S.Bach). Daher muss auch da der Chorleiter die einzelnen Stimmen (Sopran, Alt, Tenor, Bass) mit Sängern besetzen, daher gibt es auch hier Besetzungslisten. Dasselbe gilt für den Orchesterleiter, der für jedes Musikstück die einzelnen Instrumente der Partitur mit Musikern besetzen muss.

In Unternehmen ist es die Aufgabe von Recruitern die offenen Stellen im Betrieb mit geeigneten Personen zu besetzten.